# Scrapy http cache storage in memcached

Tags: python, caching, memcached, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy framework for crawling and I wonder if there is a way to use memcached as storage backend for http cache (HTTPCACHE_STORAGE option). The storages, which are available from the box, are file based and dbm, which doesn't suite my situation. Is there a possibility to use memcached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, currently there are only two http cache storage backends available built-in ([docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpcache)):

- [DBM storage backend](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#dbm-storage-backend-default)
- [Filesystem storage backend](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#filesystem-storage-backend)

There is also a [mongodb cache storage](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scmongo) implemented.

If I were you I'd implement memcached cache storage by myself. Should be pretty straightforward - it's just a class with several required by contract methods (see [dbm storage class](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/httpcache.py#L161) or [mongodb storage class](https://github.com/scrapinghub/scmongo/blob/master/scmongo/httpcache.py#L13), for example).

Hope that helps.

Comment: That was exactly the thing I wanted to avoid hoping that it is already implemented. Nevertheless thank you for reply!